# How to efficiently weight DCC (N,N'-Dicyclohexylcarbodiimide)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I have to run a reaction using N,N'-Dicyclohexylcarbodiimide and at room temperature, it is solid, but it's very hard to weigh. I know its melting point is around 40 degrees. Is it better to melt it and measure it as a liquid or is it no worth the struggle? I just don't want to have it in my hands anymore after reading it is very toxic in contact with skin and I feel like I had a few grams in contact with my hands everytime I try to break the chunks and weight it. Any tips on dealing with this reagent?

Comment: Well, you obviously shouldn't touch it with bare hands. I don't think melting is good idea though, for eg. would lead to a bit more reaction with water vapor, I guess

Comment: Good god, don't touch that stuff. Use gloves and a heavy duty metal spatula. The stoichiometry doesn't need to be perfect, so who cares if you are 5% off.

Comment: Why is it coming into contact with your hands? Do you not routinely use gloves....?

Comment: I usually break it up wih a heavy duty spatula then weigh it out - using gloves!

Comment: I do use gloves lol. But it's so messy breaking that extremely well packed solid that a lot of it goes in the gloves and of course some of it will reach my skin eventually (and I think in my first reaction I did all the grinding without gloves on and I'm still alive, so maybe I'm a survivor idk)

Comment: Try using a drill (~7mm wood drill, using a small electrical screwdriver or simply by hand).